# Svelte store is empty when accessing from a new electron BrowserWindow

Tags: electron, svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component, svelte-store

`A -> Main BrowserWindow`

`B -> New BrowserWindow`, which I create to print some files.

In B, which I create, I load a new html file, which in its script tag, inits a svelte component.

e.g

```js
import SvelteComponent from 'app/pages/component.svelte';
const component = new SvelteComponent({
  target: document.body,
});
```

This Svelte component has some markup and uses svelte/store which I import in this svelte component to display data available in store.

The problem is, in A, when I view the component, the store data is visible. But, in B, the html file when runs the above JS snippet, the store is empty. I can see the proper markup of the SvelteComponent, but there's no data, as the store is empty. (I confirmed this from `console.log`)

I don't know why is the store empty when viewed from B, if both are referencing the same file. I'm using webpack for bundling, so all imports should be available.

I would appreciate any help here, thanks!

Comment: A Svelte store is a global object living inside the window object. Your different BrowserWindow probably have a different instant of window, which means a different instance of your store. That's why you can't access the data from one window to the other despite the store existing in both.

Comment: I see. I didn't knew that about svelte store. Where can I read more about such things? Also can you suggest any possible way to overcome this behaviour?

Comment: I am not sure where you could find information about it.

Comment: And I am not very familiar with Electron, but I'd look into some form of temporary shared storage between electron windows. Maybe something similar to local storage for web browsers?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, ended up using this [neat answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58197090/13021392) from another thread (note that it would require you to set `nativeWindowOpen : true` in your `webPreferences` `BrowserWindow` configuration.